# DataTables filter default value

Tags: datatables

I'm trying to set an initial/default value for the filter input in a DataTable. Doing it with jquery on document ready causes the filter to perform a search for the value. I've searched through the DataTables documentation but can't find anything that references this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `fnInitComplete` parameter on table initialization:

```
$("#table").dataTable({
  "fnInitComplete": function(oSettings, json) {
      $("#" + oSettings.sTableId+"_filter input").val("value");
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set **oSearch** at datatable initialization

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "oSearch": {"sSearch": "Initial search"}
  } );
} )
```

Documentation: http://legacy.datatables.net/ref

Answer (score 1):

In my case for DataTables 1.10.x a little mod for [package](https://stackoverflow.com/users/991445/package) answer:

```
"fnInitComplete": function(oSettings, json) {
    $("input[aria-controls="+oSettings.sTableId+"]").val("val");
}
```